# бесконечная прокрутка с подключением к API

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, django

Так как в веб-разработке пару недель, прошу совета.

Хочу реализовать бесконечную прокрутку вот в таком вот формате :

1. Есть подключение по API с индексацией страницы (понимаю, что это делается не так, но чтобы было понятно досмотрите строку с подключением до конца )

   ```
   def main(request):
       page=str(1)
       d3 = requests.get('https://d3.ru/api/posts/?sorting=rating&threshold_date=day&page='+page).json()
   ```

   Как вы видите, каждое подключение, каждая следующая итерация, должна к `page` добавлять `+1`. В итоге при итерации должно быть :

   ```
   page=str(2)
   page=str(3)
   page=str(4)
   ```
2. Я поставил слушатель внизу страницы, чтобы знать когда пользователь достигнет низа страницы для начала следующего подключения к API с индексом `+1`

   ```
   $(window).scroll(function () {
       if ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height()) {
           alert("uzhe dno");
   });
   ```

   Насколько я понимаю, это должно быть сделано через `ajax`. Привожу сырой код этого блока:

   ```
   $.ajax({
        url: "{% url 'main' %}",
        type: "GET",
        //call main
    });
   ```

Но вот как синтаксически это правильно всё описать c запоминанием индекса и дальнейшей подгрузкой, пока что не понимаю.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> бесконечная прокрутка с подключением к API

При условии, что серверная часть у вас умеет вызывать страницы или хотя бы делится по какому-то признаку, вам подойдет `ajax`, представленый  в следующем примере.

Каждый раз когда прокрутка приходит ко "дну" документа, вызывается функция продгружающая следующую страницу, в этом примере `albomId` делит информацию на куски, которые потом можно подгружать частями.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var counter = 1;
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()) {
      // ajax вызван так как достигли дна документа
      counter++; // Следующая страница/албом
      getData(counter) // вызов следующих данных
    }
  });
  // Дефолтный вызов данных
  function getData(id = 1) {
    // Вызов по URL
    fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos?albumId=' + id)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(json => {
         // Проход по данным
        json.forEach((photo) => {
          // Карточки создаются тут
          var card =
            `<div class="row">
              <div class="col s12 m7">
                <div class="card">
                  <div class="photo-image">
                    <img src="${photo.url}" title="placeholder picsum.photos">
                    <span class="card-title">Card Title ${photo.id}</span>
                  </div>
                  <div class="card-content">
                    <p>${photo.title}</p>
                  </div>
                  <div class="card-action">
                    <a href="#">This is a link</a>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>`
          // Добваляются карточки 
          $('.container').append(card)
        })

      })
  }
  // Первый вызов 
  getData();

});
```

```css
.card img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0-rc.2/css/materialize.min.css">
<div class="container">
  <!-------- Goes here -------->
</div>
```

---

Документация:

[Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API)

[Шаблонные строки (Template literals)](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/template_strings)

[Стили Materialize](https://materializecss.com/cards.html)

Comment: Спасибо, методологию я понял

Answer (score 0):

В джиквери проверь накрутил ли ты до низа страницы. Как только ты накрутил до низа, сделай аджакс обращение и получите инфу, добавьте ее к диву. Эта функция выполняется пока вы крутите колесиком вниз.

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()) {
           // ajax call get data from server and append to the div
    }
});
```

С аджаксом я вам не помогу - учите аджакс.

И вообще поищите в гугле load more on scroll ajax; или вот ссыль https://www.thesoftwareguy.in/ajax-scroll-pagination-php-mysql/ токо там на пэхэпэ [Демо](http://demos.thesoftwareguy.in/ajax-scroll-down-pagination/)

Comment: тоисть я должен по новой парсить весь json который получу в ajax и в шаблоне и парсить? дело в том что весь парсинг у меня реализуется не в шаблоне а в views.py. Сорри за дурацкие вопросы, пока что не могу у себя в мозге построить модель как оно все работает в вебе, в мобильной разработке иначе

Comment: Я для тебя завтра сяду и выучу JSON и AJAX, чтобы нормально тебе ответить.Вообще без знания вышеперечисленных замутить такую шнягу очень просто, как по мне.(всмысле не разбираясь в парсинге json и ajax просто все подставлять куда надо)